# Is <Collection>.Count Expensive to Use?

Tags: c#, collections, count

I'm writing a cache-eject method that essentially looks like this:

```
while ( myHashSet.Count > MAX_ALLOWED_CACHE_MEMBERS )
{
    EjectOldestItem( myHashSet );
}
```

My question is about how `Count` is determined: is it just a `private` or `protected int`, or is it calculated by counting the elements each time its called?

Comment: Good question. I'd hope an internal int, since it would be fairly simple to do in most cases, but I don't know.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132433.aspx:

> Retrieving the value of this property is an O(1) operation.

This guarantees that accessing the `Count` won't iterate over the whole collection.

---

Edit: as many other posters suggested, `IEnumerable<...>.Count()` is however *not* guaranteed to be O(1). Use with care!

`IEnumerable<...>.Count()` is an extension method defined in `System.Linq.Enumerable`. The current implementation makes an explicit test if the counted `IEnumerable<T>` is indeed an instance of `ICollection<T>`, and makes use of `ICollection<T>.Count` if possible. Otherwise it traverses the `IEnumerable<T>` (possible making lazy evaluation expand) and counts items one by one.

I've not however found in the documentation whether it's guaranteed that `IEnumerable<...>.Count()` uses O(1) if possible, I only checked the implementation in .NET 3.5 with Reflector.

---

Necessary late addition: many popular containers are not derived from `Collection<T>`, but nevertheless their `Count` property is O(1) (that is, won't iterate over the whole collection). Examples are [`HashSet<T>.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355720.aspx) (this one is most likely what the OP wanted to ask about), [`Dictionary<K, V>.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhcy256f.aspx), [`LinkedList<T>.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t56y0h99.aspx), [`List<T>.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx), [`Queue<T>.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy0wwyz4.aspx), [`Stack<T>.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th379yyz.aspx) and so on.

All these collections implement `ICollection<T>` or just `ICollection`, so their `Count` is an implementation of [`ICollection<T>.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s3kzhec.aspx) (or [`ICollection.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.count.aspx)). It's not required for an implementation of `ICollection<T>.Count` to be an O(1) operation, but the ones mentioned above are doing that way, according to the documentation.

(Note aside: some containers, for instance, [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx), implement non-generic `ICollection` but not `ICollection<T>`, so they "inherit" the `Count` property only from from `ICollection`.)

Comment: Should have taken my own advice and read the Collection<T>.Count rather than just the List<T>.Count documentation! Thanks.

Comment: Please note that there's also a Count() extension method that works on IEnumerables. That is *not* guaranteed to be O(1).

Comment: You're welcome. While we're at it I should probably also mention that .Any() is a far better choice than .Count() == 0 for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 9):

Your question does not specify a *specific* Collection class so...

It depends on the Collection class.  ArrayList has an internal variable that tracks the count, as does List. However, it is implementation specific, and depending on the type of the collection, it could theoretically get recalculated on each call.

Comment: Yes.  On "Collection" the class it is O(1) as the docs state.  If you're talking about ICollection the interface, it really depends on the implementation.

Comment: @John - Its hard to tell because of how he worded the title. Was <Collection> meant to be a generic placeholder for any collection class, or was it intended to be the actual "Collection" class.

Answer (score 7):

It is an internal value, and is not calculated. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132433.aspx) states that getting the value is an O(1) operation.

Answer (score 6):

As others have noted, Count is maintained when modifying the collection. This is nearly always the case with every collection type in the framework. This is considerably different than using the Count extension method on an IEnumerable which will enumerate the collection each time.

Also, with the newer collection classes the Count property is not virtual which means that the jitter can inline the call to the Count accessor which makes it practically the same as accessing a field. In other words, very quick.

Comment: +1 for specifying that the IEnumerable<>.Count() extension method is different.  Of course, the extension method does some checking to see if the enumerable is a collection with an O(1) count before actually enumerating, but definitely something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 4):

In case of a `HashSet` it's just an internal `int` field and even `SortedSet` (a binary tree based set for .net 4) has its count in an internal field.

Answer (score 3):

According to Reflector, it is implemented as

```
public int Count{ get; }
```

so it is defined by the derived type

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick note. Be ware that there are two ways to count a collection in .NET 3.5 when System.Linq is used. For a normal collection, the first choice should be to use the Count property, for the reasons already described in other answers.

An alternative method, via the LINQ .Count() extension method, is also available. The intriguing thing about .Count() is that it can be called on ANY enumerable, regardless of whether the underlying class implements ICollection or not, or whether it has a Count property. If you ever do call .Count() however, be aware that it WILL iterate over the collection to dynamically generate a count. That generally results in O(n) complexity.

The only reason I wanted to note this is, using IntelliSense, it is often easy to accidentally end up using the Count() extension rather than the Count property.

Answer (score 1):

It's an internal `int` that get incremented each time a new item is added to the collection.